# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured when using custom datasource format

Tags: java, spring

When I start my spring boot application, it shows this error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

this is my datasource configuation:

```
spring.datasource.type = com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource

## master
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.name = primary_db
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/report-fat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&transformedBitIsBoolean=true&useSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.username = root
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.password = LogSsDk87Fm2RXSVHMnwjvtA5Nncs2kT7nWrRkB06BcBNPwyTnaf60jNG+ENeyuhYm+X1fWj59XHFiXqiw==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.connection-properties = config.decrypt=true;config.decrypt.key=MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKwORT+pNusNtC433Kdmk18WTYbxu0gGAWBccQrK+h0PHElZrEsJDqj9yvNq2Rwzw6d/YwECio3bS+yMCAwEAAQ==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#
# slave
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.name = primary_db
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/report-fat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&transformedBitIsBoolean=true&useSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.username = root
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.password = LogSsDk87Fm2RXSVHMnwjvtA5Nncs2kRT7nWrRkB06BcBNPwyTnbd+af60jNG+ENeyuhYm+X1fWj59XHFiXqiw==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.connection-properties = config.decrypt=true;config.decrypt.key=MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKwORT+pNusNtC433Kdmk18WTYbxu0gGAWBccQrK+h0PHElZrEsJDqj9yvNq2Rwzwx9PoWRn6d/YwECio3bS+yMCAwEAAQ==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

and this is my datasource config:

```
    package com.sportswin.soa.illidan.config;

import com.alibaba.druid.spring.boot.autoconfigure.DruidDataSourceBuilder;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.PaginationInterceptor;
import com.sportswin.soa.misc.config.db.ReadWriteSplitRoutingDataSource;
import com.sportswin.soa.misc.constant.db.ConstantPool;
import com.sportswin.soa.misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor;
import com.sportswin.soa.misc.spring.aspect.db.UseSlaveAspect;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 */
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.sportswin.soa.illidan.dao"}, sqlSessionTemplateRef = "sqlSessionTemplate")
public class DataSourceConfig {


    /**
     * 数据库连接池类型
     */
    @Value("${spring.datasource.type}")
    private Class<? extends DataSource> dataSourceType;


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Qualifier(value = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    @DependsOn({ "masterDataSource", "slaveDataSource" })
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource,
                                 @Qualifier("slaveDataSource") DataSource slaveDataSource) {
        System.out.println(masterDataSource.toString());
        System.out.println(slaveDataSource.toString());
        ReadWriteSplitRoutingDataSource writeSplitRoutingDataSource = new ReadWriteSplitRoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        targetDataSources.put(ConstantPool.MASTER_KEY, masterDataSource);
        targetDataSources.put(ConstantPool.SLAVE_KEY, slaveDataSource);
        writeSplitRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        writeSplitRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource);


        List<String> slaveDataSourceNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        slaveDataSourceNames.add(ConstantPool.SLAVE_KEY);

        UseSlaveAspect.setSlaveDataSourceNames(slaveDataSourceNames);
        return writeSplitRoutingDataSource;
    }



    /**
     * 主数据库（写数据库）
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "masterDataSource", destroyMethod = "close", initMethod = "init")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        System.out.println("主库");
        return DruidDataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /**
     * 从数据库1（只读数据库）
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "slaveDataSource", destroyMethod = "close", initMethod = "init")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave")
    public DataSource slaveDataSource(){
        System.out.println("从库");
        return DruidDataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PaginationInterceptor paginationInterceptor;
    @Autowired
    private DefaultTimeInterceptor defaultTimeInterceptor;


    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setConfigLocation(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"));
        bean.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:mybatis/mapper/*/*.xml"));

        Interceptor[] plugins = {paginationInterceptor,defaultTimeInterceptor};
        bean.setPlugins(plugins);

        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionTemplate")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(@Qualifier("sqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }

}
```

why would this happen and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: you have to specify jdbcurl

Comment: what is  the difference? @Soni

Comment: Based on your driver, which is mysql here, the property which gets transformed internally to url is jdbcurl, hence you should use this in your properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try moving your datasource type inside each datasource.

```
remove it from here -> spring.datasource.type = com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource

## master
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.type = com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.name = primary_db
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/report-fat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&transformedBitIsBoolean=true&useSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.username = root
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.password = LogSsDk87Fm2RXSVHMnwjvtA5Nncs2kT7nWrRkB06BcBNPwyTnaf60jNG+ENeyuhYm+X1fWj59XHFiXqiw==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.connection-properties = config.decrypt=true;config.decrypt.key=MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKwORT+pNusNtC433Kdmk18WTYbxu0gGAWBccQrK+h0PHElZrEsJDqj9yvNq2Rwzw6d/YwECio3bS+yMCAwEAAQ==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.master.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#
# slave
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.type = com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.name = primary_db
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/report-fat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&transformedBitIsBoolean=true&useSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.username = root
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.password = LogSsDk87Fm2RXSVHMnwjvtA5Nncs2kRT7nWrRkB06BcBNPwyTnbd+af60jNG+ENeyuhYm+X1fWj59XHFiXqiw==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.connection-properties = config.decrypt=true;config.decrypt.key=MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKwORT+pNusNtC433Kdmk18WTYbxu0gGAWBccQrK+h0PHElZrEsJDqj9yvNq2Rwzwx9PoWRn6d/YwECio3bS+yMCAwEAAQ==
spring.datasource.druid.illidan.slave.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: I tried this way but it seems not work for this situation. @Boug

Comment: then please also post the code for return DruidDataSourceBuilder.create().build(); and also the other configurations files and properties that you have

Comment: I pasted the whole config about the database @Boug

Comment: try changing from  driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver to driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver remove .cj.

Comment: my mysql driver version is above 6: `api "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18"` @Boug

Comment: please also post DruidDataSourceBuilder.create().build();